# In this situation, best practice to create an ORACLE VIEW or TABLE?

Tags: database, oracle, view, database-administration

In order to be able to report out oracle logons I have a query to find logons to the system. I want to be able to output the query results to a table or view in order to then report on this table/view. The underlying tables that the query is based on do not keep historical data hence my need for a new table/view.
Query will run 3 times a day to gather logon information at those times.

Is it best to create a new table and append the daily information updates or would a view be better practice? I'm unsure on the updating of a view as the underlying tables needs to be present, if that's correct.

Thanks

Comment: I'd be curious as to these "underlying tables" that you query multiple times daily to collect logon information.  It sounds very much like you've reinvented oracle's own AUDIT, along with the DBA_SESSIONS view.

Comment: You probably mean the `DBA_AUDIT_SESSION` view @EdStevens. And yes, the *best practice* is create nothing but use existing;)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - yes, DBA_AUDIT_SESSIONS.  Thanks for the correction.    :-)

Comment: Yeah that would be great but the DBA_AUDIT_SESSIONS table is blank in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view won't help at all. It is just a stored query and doesn't contain any data; it just reflects what you have in underlying table(s).

Therefore, you'll need a "history" table which will *permanently* hold data you're interested in.